# Monotony of integral series

Tags: integration, monotone-functions

$I_n=\int _0^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\tan ^n\left(x\right)dx,\: n \ge 2$

I have to find the monotony of $I_n$.

I calculated and proved $I_n + I_{n+2} = \frac{1}{n+1}$.
Also, the first term $I_2 = 1 - \frac{\pi}{4}$

But I don't know how to find $I_{n+1}-I_{n}$ or if that's the way to go.

Comment: For every $x$ in the range, $\tan x<1$, so that $\tan^{n+1}x<\tan^n x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Can post as answer... I haven't thought it was that simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x$ in the range, $\tan x<1$, so that $\tan^{n+1}x<\tan^n x$.

Comment: +1. A small remark though: classically, $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is thought of as in the range, so probably $\tan{x}\le 1$ is better. But since the function is positive on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$, the inequality on the integral will of course be strict.

Comment: @Scientifica: I did expect the remark but didn't want to clutter the answer with this detail. I was tempted to write "in the open range" but I feared that this would be confusing to the OP. As you know, the set where equality holds has null measure.

Comment: I don't think that "open range" would confuse the OP but apart from that you're right.